# Storing bash commands in python list

Tags: python, bash

I want to run a bash command and append it's output in a list. I tried

```
import commands

v = commands.getstatusoutput("ls")
```

but v will be an output of (0,"file1\nfile2\ndir1\n")

I could process the 1st (0th based) element in `v` but that means I would have to scan through the string. I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to approach this. I do not have to `commands`. I am open to other ways to perform the same task

Comment: Why do you've to scan through the string? You can simply use `v[1]` to get the output or if you only want command's output then simply use `commands.getoutput()`. Or **better** use `subprocess` module's `check_output` method because `commands` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, you only have to split the string on the newline character:

```
output = v[1].split("\n")
```

In general, you should use the Python equivalent where possible instead of calling out to the shell:

```
files = os.listdir(".")
```

For shell commands without a Python equivalent, look at the `subprocess` module, but
having to parse the output is not non-Pythonic, it's just something you'll have to do.